# How to let brand stay on the right on collapse in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I would like to have a brand on the right and the navigation on the left. It works on a big screen, but on collapse the brand is going to the left and the "burger button" to the right. I would like to have it vice versa (menu always on the left and brand always right). My only idea now is to make it over custom css, but I would like to have it over bootstrap classes if possible.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-right">
        <img src="logo.jpg" />
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>     
      </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li ><a class="main_nav_link" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li ><a class="main_nav_link" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li ><a class="main_nav_link" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the bootstrap classes: **[`pull-left` and `pull-right`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)**

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-right pull-right">
```

and

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
```

Check if [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnmvra17/) is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Work like a charm.

Comment: Great! Happy to help. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted'. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers ;)